# Pulling from GIT only changed files and folder structure

Tags: git

I have a question about using GIT.  Lets say I have a folder structure like this:

```
-var
  -www
    -prod
      -portal
```

Now I usually just git pull into the prod folder, mv portal portalBAK and then change name of pulled git from mygitrepo-businessname to portal
This seems cumbersome and not very easily done.

How could I pull just changed files and have them go into the portal folder?

Im new to GIT and just trying to find the easiest way.  Lets assume I have not initiated git yet on this folder :)

I will also add that I have another server for development that pushes to the git repo.   Not sure if thats useful info.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can name the destination when you do `git clone`: `git clone YOUR_REPO portal`
2. If you want to simplify the backup part, you can append a timestamp to your backup: `mv portal portal.bak.$(date +'%Y%m%d%H%m%S')`
3. I assume you also want to "update" the `portal` folder, then you can always do a `git pull` in this folder. If your remote commits on another host is not always clean to merge, you can do `git fetch && git reset --hard origin/master` in `portal` folder, this will ignore any local changes and force sync with the remote git repo.